# Do API Connections retain their authorisation state indefinitely?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I've created an [Azure Automation API Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureautomation/) to use in a [Logic App action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list). As [the docs explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#authorize-oauth-connections), when the API Connection is first created it requires authorisation before it can talk to Automation:

```
PS C:\> $conn = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName my-rg -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections -Name azureautomation
PS C:\> $conn.Properties.statuses

status target error
------ ------ -----
Error  token  @{code=Unauthenticated; message=This connection is not authenticated.}
```

Following the docs I can open the connection in the Logic App Designer and authenticate as a user with permissions to create Automation jobs (e.g. one with the [Automation Job Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-role-based-access-control) role). The connection then shows as authenticated and the action successfully creates jobs:

```
PS C:\> $conn = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName my-rg -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections -Name azureautomation
PS C:\> $conn.Properties.statuses

status
------
Connected

PS C:\> $conn.Properties.authenticatedUser

name
----
username@example.com
```

Clearly the connection hasn't just been *authenticated*, it's also been *authorised*. What's not clear to me is which [authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens#how-each-flow-emits-tokens-and-codes) the Logic App Designer has followed, and in particular whether the connection will automatically refresh its [access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) without further intervention. This isn't just academic: what I want to know is **will the connection silently lose authorisation at some future point?**

I'm building this for a customer who's new to Azure, so I want to keep the solution as simple as possible. They're familiar with the idea of a service account in the on-prem AD world, but AAD service principals are new to them. Is it safe to rely on one-time manual authorisation through the Logic App Designer, or is [using a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#authenticate-connections) the only reliable way to ensure the connection stays authorised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [using a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#authenticate-connections) is more reliable in your scenario, if you use a user account to authorize the connection, the connection maybe broken as an undetermined issue e.g. the password changed in the future. If you use the service principal to authorize, we just need to use a never expired client secret, then it will never lose authorization.