# How to prevent o365 API connection from becoming invalidated from expired access token when using azure logic apps send email action

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic Apps with send shared mailbox email action. The action works but after several days it becomes invalid by expired access token then. I need to change the connection by re-authenticating.

How to avoid this with shared mailboxes? I don't have the issue with a normal mailbox but those cost licensing.

I just keep creating a new o365 API connection but it gets invalidated after several days.

Comment: You can authenticate the same API Connection as well without needing to change the connection

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the service principal with never expired client secret to keep the API Connection authenticated as started in this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840381/do-api-connections-retain-their-authorisation-state-indefinitely).
- Alternate way is to re-authenticate the same API Connection using the below given PowerShell script.

```bash
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'YourRG',
    [string] $ResourceLocation = 'eastus | westus | etc.',
    [string] $api = 'office365 | dropbox | dynamicscrmonline | etc.',
    [string] $ConnectionName = 'YourConnectionName',
    [string] $subscriptionId = '***********',
    [bool] $createConnection =  $true | $false
)
 #region mini window, made by Scripting Guy Blog
    Function Show-OAuthWindow {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
    $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{Width=600;Height=800}
    $web  = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join "%20")) }
    $DocComp  = {
            $Global:uri = $web.Url.AbsoluteUri
            if ($Global:Uri -match "error=[^&]*|code=[^&]*") {$form.Close() }
    }
    $web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true
    $web.Add_DocumentCompleted($DocComp)
    $form.Controls.Add($web)
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    }
    #endregion

#login to get an access code 

Login-AzureRmAccount 

#select the subscription

$subscription = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

#if the connection wasn't alrady created via a deployment
if($createConnection)
{
    $connection = New-AzureRmResource -Properties @{"api" = @{"id" = "subscriptions/" + $subscriptionId + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/" + $ResourceLocation + "/managedApis/" + $api}; "displayName" = $ConnectionName; } -ResourceName $ConnectionName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceLocation -Force
}
#else (meaning the conneciton was created via a deployment) - get the connection
else{
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
}
Write-Host "connection status: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]

$parameters = @{
    "parameters" = ,@{
    "parameterName"= "token";
    "redirectUrl"= "https://ema1.exp.azure.com/ema/default/authredirect"
    }
}

#get the links needed for consent
$consentResponse = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "listConsentLinks" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force

$url = $consentResponse.Value.Link 

#prompt user to login and grab the code after auth
Show-OAuthWindow -URL $url

$regex = '(code=)(.*)$'
    $code  = ($uri | Select-string -pattern $regex).Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Write-output "Received an accessCode: $code"

if (-Not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($code)) {
    $parameters = @{ }
    $parameters.Add("code", $code)
    # NOTE: errors ignored as this appears to error due to a null response

    #confirm the consent code
    Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action "confirmConsentCode" -ResourceId $connection.ResourceId -Parameters $parameters -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
}

#retrieve the connection
$connection = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/connections" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ConnectionName
Write-Host "connection status now: " $connection.Properties.Statuses[0]
```

- This script will re-authenticate the same API connection and change the status from **Error** to **Connected**.

[image]